# Implement a Media library or playlist using file management in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am making a media player using javafx & eclipse. I have used 3 classes in my program. I am almost done. But I am facing a problem to implement a media library. I want to implement my media library or playlist using file management system in java. I know for this I need to use directory & file locations. As it is my first project & I am not that good in using file management in java so I really don't understand how to use them correctly & how to implement my library using file management. The main class of my code is given below. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main extends Application{

Player player;
FileChooser fc;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MenuItem open= new MenuItem("Open");
    //MenuItem library= new MenuItem("Library");
    Menu file= new Menu("File");
    Menu library= new Menu("Playlist");
    MenuBar menu= new MenuBar();
    primaryStage.setTitle("My Media Player");

    file.getItems().add(open);
    menu.getMenus().add(file);
    menu.getMenus().add(library);


    fc= new FileChooser();

    open.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            player.player.pause();
            File file= fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

            if(file!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    player= new Player(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
                    Scene scene= new Scene(player, 1280, 690, javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);
                    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                }
                catch(MalformedURLException el)
                {
                    el.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    library.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });


    player= new Player("file:///E:/duniya.mp4");

    player.setTop(menu);
    Scene sc= new Scene(player, 1280, 690, javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);

    sc.setRoot(player);



    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    launch(args);

}
```

}

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  What specific problem are you struggling with regarding java and working with the file system?

Comment: I was trying read files from .txt document. But getting errors. Actually I can't read the file locations correctly...